# Reproduce right-align behaviour of `multline` inside `align` environment using LyX

Tags: equations, lyx, align

The `multline` environment is great for long equations. For example,

```
\begin{multline}
First line of my long equation \\
second line of my long equation
\end{multline}
```

produces output in which the second equation is right-aligned:

```
First line of my long equation
      second line of my long equation
```

I would like to reproduce the same behaviour inside an `align` environment to align equalities but also right-align some lines. I.e. the output should look like

```
    A = first line of A
                     second line of A
other = first line of other
                 second line of other
```

Comment: i don't have an answer, but a related question.  if these equations are numbered, where would you like the number to be placed if it's at the right -- on the last line of each equation, or centered between the lines?

Comment: Ideally, centred for each set that belongs together but I am also happy to add the equation number to the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `multlined` facility of `mathtools` can be used here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 A &= \begin{multlined}[t]
     \text{first line of A}\\
     \text{second line of A}
     \end{multlined}\\
 \text{other} &= \begin{multlined}[t]
     \text{first line of other}\\
     \text{second line of other}
     \end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

it's necessary to specify top-alignment with the optional `[t]` so that
the lines of the `multline`d expression aren't vertically centered on the
left-hand side.  unfortunately, this has the effect of putting the
equation number on the first line; i don't have a workaround for that.

[image: output of example code]